# How to find multiple substrings

Tags: c#, substring

I have stored date of birth var char format:

Example: 1989-8-15

I want to find out sub string from it i.e I want separate year, month and date. I have tried it with following code:

```
string dateOfbirth = (string)(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "dob"));

int length = (dateOfbirth).Length;
int index1 = dateOfbirth.IndexOf('-');
int index2 = dateOfbirth.IndexOf('-', index1 + 1);
string year = dateOfbirth.Substring(0, index1);
string month = dateOfbirth.Substring(index+1, index2-1);
string day = dateOfbirth.Substring(index2, length);
```

I am getting an error. Please suggest a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: Why don't you use something like the following to achieve this effect:
`string[] arrDateOfbirth = dateOfbirth.Split('-');`
Then you can select a value by stepping through the array...

Answer (score 5):

You can try this

```
string [] date = dateOfbirth.Split('-');
string year = date[0];
string month = date[1];
string day = date[2];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime dob = DateTime.ParseExact("1989-8-15","yyyy-M-dd",null);
Console.WriteLine(dob.Year);
Console.WriteLine(dob.Month);
Console.WriteLine(dob.Day);
```

Clean and easy.

*UPD*: changed `Parse` to `ParseExact` with a custom date format

Comment: Instead of `.Parse` you should use `.TryParseExact` to avoid exception due to different culure settings

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help:

```
string st= "1989-8-15"; / 
string st = (string)(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "dob"));

string [] stArr = st.Split('-');
```

So, you now have an array with dob items.

Answer (score 0):

To actually answer your question:

```
string dateOfbirth = "1989-8-15";

int length = (dateOfbirth).Length;
int index1 = dateOfbirth.IndexOf('-');
int index2 = dateOfbirth.IndexOf('-', index1 + 1);

string year = dateOfbirth.Substring(0, index1);
string month = dateOfbirth.Substring(index1 + 1, index2 - index1 - 1);
string day = dateOfbirth.Substring(index2 + 1, length - index2 - 1);
```

It's just a matter of providing the correct parameters to the `Substring` method.

Using `dateOfBirth.Split('-')` would probably be at better solution for your problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TryParseExact` to avoid exception due to different culture settings

```
DateTime dateValue;
var dateString="1989-08-15";
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
{
// parse successfull
Console.WriteLine(dateValue.Year);
Console.WriteLine(dateValue.Month);
Console.WriteLine(dateValue.Day);
}
```